# IP redirect while showing message

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an idea, it is a little complex and i am not sure how to go about doing it.
For example,
I want to redirect 123.456.789.10 from `http://mywebsite.com` to `http://google.com` but
have a temporary page like `http://mywebsite.com/messages/go_away.html` to show up for about 5-10
 seconds first then have that page automatically redirect them to `http://google.com`,
so they see the message for 5-10 seconds before getting automatically redirected.

```
keep in mind i may want to add more than 1 IP address or range like this.
xxx.xxx.
xxx.xxx.
xxx.xxx.
and so on.
```

xxx.xxx. would be the 1st 2 sets of numbers How would i go about doing that?
thanks in advance,

Comment: What does `123.456.`, `789.10.`, and `11.12` mean?

Comment: those are the 1st 2 sets of ip address eg. xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx but im looking to only use the first 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** 
Use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(123\.456\.|789\.10|11\.12)
RewriteRule !^temp-page /temp-page.html [L,NC,R]
```

**Step 2:**

Then inside `/temp-page.html` use code like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://www.google.com/">
<h1>This temporary page will redirect to www.google.com in 5 seconds</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://google.com/">
```